# Matlab: Lost on reading weird lat lon format

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude

I like to read in the locations of oil platforms using this [file](http://www.gomr.boemre.gov/homepg/pubinfo/repcat/arcinfo/zipped/8322_ascii_platforms.pdf) in Matlab. I obtained the file from [here](http://www.gomr.boemre.gov/homepg/pubinfo/repcat/arcinfo/index.html). "Platform.gen" looks like this:

Id Lat Lon
1 0.100000000000000D+02 0.890000000000000D+02
2 -0.941577040000000D+02 0.294488400000000D+02
3 -0.941241560000000D+02 0.292748680000000D+02
4 -0.941225830000000D+02 0.292251370000000D+02
5 -0.943647730000000D+02 0.292845940000000D+02

I read it into Matlab using:

> [id lat
>   lon]=textread('platform.gen','%s %s
>   %s');

However, I am lost on how to decode the lat/lon values...help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest instead using the conversion specifier `%f` to read the values. This will automatically handle the format for the double-precision floating point numbers. The character `D` is just another way to display [scientific notation](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/lab/197/fortran/fort3.htm#double), so `0.10D+02` is `10` in double precision:

```
>> [id,lat,lon] = textread('platform.gen','%u %f %f','headerlines',1)

id =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5

lat =

   10.0000
  -94.1577
  -94.1242
  -94.1226
  -94.3648

lon =

   89.0000
   29.4488
   29.2749
   29.2251
   29.2846
```

Also, the function [TEXTREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textread.html) will be removed in a future MATLAB version in favor of [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html), which you could use like so:

```
>> fid = fopen('platform.gen','r');
>> data = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','HeaderLines',1,'CollectOutput',true);
>> fclose(fid);
>> data{1}

ans =

    1.0000   10.0000   89.0000
    2.0000  -94.1577   29.4488
    3.0000  -94.1242   29.2749
    4.0000  -94.1226   29.2251
    5.0000  -94.3648   29.2846
```

Comment: +1, exactly what I was looking for. As always, gnovice, you're the best